# How to use tee to capture STDOUT from a code block to a filename defined within the block?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, variable, tee

I want to send *STDOUT* for a script block to a file which name is defined by a variable within the block. However, when I use *tee*, it seems the variable outside the block doesn't exist anymore. Without *tee*, the variable still exists.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
    log="mylog.txt"
    echo log: $log
} |tee $log

echo log: $log
```

Result:

```
log: mylog.txt
log:
```

and no *mylog.txt* file produced by *tee*.

Comment: Try `echo log: $$ '->' $log` instead of just `echo log: $log`. Both `echo` instructions are run in a different shell instance.

Comment: Piped processes are run in a subshell.

Answer (score 3):

```
 #!/bin/bash
 log="mylog.txt"
 {
     echo log: $log
 } |tee $log
```

The pipeline causes the command list to be executed in a sub-shell. As the variable was in a different sub-shell, this could not be communicated up.  Thus you have to move the variable up into a common context to be properly used.

Comment: is there a way to do it without a pipe? I need to define my variable within the block. Any other way than tee to log both STDOUT and STDERR for the entire script execution would make my day.

Comment: @SébastienClément [What is your actual problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

A named pipe could work for you. With only a little bit more work you can get one robustly and without having to setup `trap`s or similar to handle file-system cleanup afterward - you just do the cleanup beforehand.

```
pipe=/tmp/$$pipe log=mylog.txt
mkfifo "$pipe"; exec 3<>"$pipe"
{ rm "$pipe"; tee "$log"; } <&3 >/dev/tty &
pipe=$!; exec >&3 3>&-
```

There. From this moment on all of the script's output is being written to a *(used-to-be)* named pipe that is being read by a back-grounded `tee` process. The named pipe's special file has already been removed from the file-system and so it need not be cleaned-up later and the only references to it that remain are the file-descriptors assigned to your script's `stdout` and `tee`'s `stdin`.

That said, it could be wise to setup at least one `trap`:

```
trap "kill PIPE $pipe" 0
```

...just to ensure that `tee` doesn't hang out in the background after your script exits.

If you run into buffering issues - which shouldn't be a problem, I think, since `tee` has an open line on `/dev/tty` - you might try your luck calling `tee` via `stdbuf`. `stdbuf`'s `man` page specifically hedges its bets where is `tee` concerned though - it notes `tee`  as an application that is likely to readjust its own buffers after invocation - but is more positive about the interaction than it is for `dd` anyway.

Comment: Hey mikeserv, I took some ideas from this answer and used them to write https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/541908/135943, but I feel there are nuances I may have missed—I couldn't get my answer to work by deleting the named pipe before use.  If you'd like to take a look I'd appreciate it.  :)